# Object pink in render (no textures are in use)

Tags: rendering, materials

I'm using cycles, with very basic Principled BSDF materials without any texture images. In the Material tab, the materials are shown just fine, but in when I render my object, all materials show up as pink (as though an image was missing).

What am I missing?

Comment: HDRI file, maybe?

Comment: Could it be that you have an environment image texture that has no assigned image? This would make the whole scene pink.

Comment: Ah yes... not sure how it happened, but it was the sky plugin (had to switch to another background and back..). So I guess you were both right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently the answer is:

If everything looks pink in the render and there are no textures missing in the materials of the objects, the first thing to check should always be the HDRI lighting setup in the Node Editor:

[image]