# - Blender Texture Fail Cycles Vs Eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, eevee-render-engine

For whatever reason, the texture will display on Eevee Render but not Cycles Render? What is causing this and how do I fix this? [image: Showing texture as missing even though it is not missing and works fine with Eevee]

Comment: Could be a missing HDRI in the world background. Do you use one?

Comment: Why would HDRI background impact Cycles registering the texture PNG of the donut in Render view?

Comment: Most image textures show a file extension (ex: .jpg, .png, .exr, etc...) next to the name, but your does not. Why is that? Did you bake the image in blender?

Comment: @TinyTRex A *missing* HDRI can tint everything pink. And since your icing is pinkish, too... [Object pink in render (no textures are in use)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/120045/107598)